# Return Maximum Sum SubArray from set of elements in an array Problem

Tags: java, algorithm

```
public class MaxSumSubArray
{
    public int findSum (int[] arr)
    {
        int maxSum;
        //This covers when we have just one element
        if(arr.length == 1) {
            maxSum = arr[0];
        } else {
             maxSum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                int sum = arr[i]; // -1
                    for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
                      // This is the case when your new elem is greater than the sum of prev elements
                       if(arr[j] > sum + arr[j]) {
                            sum = arr[j];
                        } else {
                            sum = sum + arr[j];
                        }
                        if (sum > maxSum) {
                            maxSum = sum;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        return maxSum;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4};
        MaxSumSubArray subArray = new MaxSumSubArray();
        System.out.println("MAx sum is:"+ subArray.findSum(arr));
    }
}
```

I have written this code for maximum Sum subarray, I am using brute force approach.

Input: nums = [-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4]
Output: 6
Explanation: [4,-1,2,1] has the largest sum = 6.

This code is working for almost every set of input except one [-1,-2]. Can somebody help which I am missing here. Thanks

Comment: What exactly is this kind of "sum"? What are its properties? Because from what I understand it's not a normal integer sum...

Comment: In this example [-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4] -- max sum is 6 which is coming from this subarray [4,-1,2,1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not reinitialize the sum variable in the second loop, you should choose the largest value after each add arr[j] to sum.

```
public int findSum (int[] arr)
{
    int maxSum;
    //This covers when we have just one element
    if(arr.length == 1) {
        maxSum = arr[0];
    } else {
        maxSum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            int sum = arr[i]; // -1
            if (sum > maxSum) {
                maxSum = sum;
            }
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
                sum = sum + arr[j];
                if (sum > maxSum) {
                    maxSum = sum;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return maxSum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int findMaxSubarraySum(int[] nums) {
int maxSum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            // calculate the sum of subarray `nums[i…j]`
            int sum = 0;    // reset sum
            // do for each subarray ending at `j`
            for (int j = i; j < nums.length; j++) {
                sum += nums[j];
                if (sum > maxSum) {
                    maxSum = sum;
                }
            }
        }
        return maxSum;
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).